# How do I mention duplicate host ip in Ansible inventory file

Tags: ansible, duplicates, ansible-inventory

I have the below entry in the host file

cat server.hosts

```
[mum_servers]
10.12.34.213 USER=user1
10.12.34.213 USER=root

[all_hosts:children]
mum_servers
```

Below is how I run my playbook where I specify hosts as `all_hosts`

```
ansible-playbook -i server.hosts test.yml
```

However the playbook runs 10.12.34.213 only once and not twice as mentioned in the hosts file.

I understand that Ansible treats duplicate entries for hosts as a single entry, however can you please suggest how can I change my server.hosts file to make 10.12.34.213 run twice first with `user1` and then with `root` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create different hosts using aliases

```
my_host_as_user1 ansible_host=10.12.34.213 USER=user1
my_host_as_root ansible_host=10.12.34.213 USER=root
```